# Making a sprite always point to another sprite in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I have a player sprite (`playerTexture`) and a crosshair sprite (`crossTexture`) in my game. I need to make the player sprite always face towards the crosshair.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried doing it myself but the math involved boggles my mind. I know there's a rotation parameter in the `spriteBatch.Draw()` method but I'm unsure how to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rotating a sprite to following another sprite is mostly just triangle math.  I was going to try and type up a good explanation, but then i found this posting - which includes pictures to help you along the way, which hopefully will help you understand what's going on and what you need to do.

http://www.berecursive.com/2008/c/rotating-a-sprite-towards-an-object-in-xna

Comment: In the end I looked at some samples on the XNA website and there was a pre-made project that demonstrated what I want. Although I'll probably go through the tutorial you found so I can learn exactly what's going on. Thanks! :)